# Beautiful Soup 4: How to replace a tag with text and another tag?

Tags: python, html, replace, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to replace a tag with another tag and put the contents of the old tag before the new one. For example:

I want to change this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is the <span id="1">first</span> paragraph</p>
<p>This is the <span id="2">second</span> paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

into this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is the first<sup>1</sup> paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second<sup>2</sup> paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can easily find all `spans` with `find_all()`, get the number from the id attribute and replace one tag with another tag using `replace_with()`, but how do I replace a tag with text *and* a new tag or insert text before a replaced tag?

Comment: +1 @alecxe - I always see him/her answering it quickly and accurately

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idea is to find every `span` tag with `id` attribute (`span[id]` [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)), use [`insert_after()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) to insert a `sup` tag after it and [`unwrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to replace the tag with it's contents:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<html>
<body>
<p>This is the <span id="1">first</span> paragraph</p>
<p>This is the <span id="2">second</span> paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for span in soup.select('span[id]'):
    # insert sup tag after the span
    sup = soup.new_tag('sup')
    sup.string = span['id']
    span.insert_after(sup)

    # replace the span tag with it's contents
    span.unwrap()

print soup
```

Prints:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is the first<sup>1</sup> paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second<sup>2</sup> paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. I had read the BS documentation, but I obviously missed the section about **wrap()** and **unwrap()**, which is the key to solving this problem.

Comment: `.replaceWith()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937126#32938576