# BeautifulSoup replaceWith() method adding escaped html, want it unescaped

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I have a python method ([thank to this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/)) that takes some html and wraps `<a>` tags around ONLY unformatted links, using BeautifulSoup and Django's urlize:

```
from django.utils.html import urlize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def html_urlize(self, text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    print(soup)

    textNodes = soup.findAll(text=True)
    for textNode in textNodes:
        if textNode.parent and getattr(textNode.parent, 'name') == 'a':
            continue  # skip already formatted links
        urlizedText = urlize(textNode)
        textNode.replaceWith(urlizedText)

    print(soup)

    return str(soup)
```

Sample input text (as output by the first print statement) is this:

```
this is a formatted link <a href="http://google.ca">http://google.ca</a>, this one is unformatted and should become formatted: http://google.ca
```

The resulting return text (as output by the second print statement) is this:

```
this is a formatted link <a href="http://google.ca">http://google.ca</a>, this one is unformatted and should become formatted: &lt;a href="http://google.ca"&gt;http://google.ca&lt;/a&gt;
```

As you can see, it is formatting the link, but it's doing it with escaped html, so when I print it in a template `{{ my.html|safe }}` it doesn't render as html.

So how can I get these tags that are added with urlize to be unescaped, and render properly as html? I suspect this has something do do with me using it as a method instead of a template filter?  I can't actually find the docs on this method, it doesn't appear in [django.utils.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.html).

Edit: It appears the escaping actually happen in this line: `textNode.replaceWith(urlizedText)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can turn your urlizedText string in to a new BeautifulSoup object and it will be treated as a tag in it's own right rather than text within one (which is escaped as you'd expect)

```
from django.utils.html import urlize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def html_urlize(self, text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    print(soup)

    textNodes = soup.findAll(text=True)
    for textNode in textNodes:
        if textNode.parent and getattr(textNode.parent, 'name') == 'a':
            continue  # skip already formatted links
        urlizedText = urlize(textNode)
        textNode.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(urlizedText, "html.parser"))

    print(soup)

    return str(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be where you're trying to use BeautifulSoup to replace a text node with one containing HTML entities.

One way to achieve what you want is to build up a new string with the output of urlize (which doesn't seem to care whether a link is already formatted or not).

```
from django.utils.html import urlize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def html_urlize(self, text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    finalFragments = []
    textNodes = soup.findAll(text=True)
    for textNode in textNodes:
        if getattr(textNode.parent, 'name') == 'a':
            finalFragments.append(str(textNode.parent))
        else:
            finalFragments.append(urlize(textNode))

    return str("".join(finalFragments))
```

However, if all you want to do is to render it in a template, you can just call urlize on your input string as a template tag -

```
{{input_string|urlize}}
```

Comment: From docs: "If urlize is applied to text that already contains HTML markup, things won’t work as expected. Apply this filter only to plain text."  So `{{input_string|urlize}}` won't work.  As I mentioned in the question and example text, I'm starting with html.

Comment: I tried the fragment method and it properly formats the link, but it removes the first, already formatted link! (See example text from question)

Comment: I edited my answer to include your check for an existing <a> tag. Seems to work for your example text.

Comment: Ok, maybe I screwed up, I included the check when I tested it, but I'll try again.

Comment: Almost there, thank you!  So this is working on the example text, but because you remove the soup, it only builds up textnodes, all other html (non text-nodes) is stripped from the html: `<hr> <img> <br>` etc.

Comment: Have posted a new answer :)