# BeautifulSoup replace html tag with another html tag

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a script that takes some html and rewrites some of the tags. Specifically what I'm trying to do is store href tags with a more human readable format and then generate more complex links with that.

I'm using BeautifulSoup for that, but my problem is I'm trying to feed a generated string to it and it keeps replacing my tags with wacky text representations of them:

```
def parse_hyperlinks(line, replace):
    new_line = str(line)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new_line, "html.parser")

    links = soup.findAll("href")

    for href in links:
        href.replaceWith(replace) # <- this guy

    new_line = str(soup)

    return new_line

line = "<href link=\"google.com\" internal=\"false\">google</href>"
replace = "<a href=\"google.com\" data-attached-link=\"{{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Web&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;google.com&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;google.com&quot;}}\" class=\"wz-link inserted\">google</a>"
print parse_hyperlinks(line, replace)

$ python parse.py
'\\&lt;a href="google.com" data-attached-link="{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;Web&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;url&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;google.com&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;title&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;google.com&amp;quot;}" class="wz-link inserted"\\&gt;google\\&lt;/a\\&gt;'
```

How can I get it to give me the text with my tags intact?

**UPDATE**: Removed irrelevant code

Comment: Don't use sentences like `href.attrs["name"] if href.attrs.get("name") else ""` - just `href.attrs.get("name","")` is enough. And what is `create_hyperlink(text, link, name, is_internal)`? Please add this code

Comment: It returns this `"<a href=\"google.com\" data-attached-link=\"{{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Web&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;google.com&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;google.com&quot;}}\" class=\"wz-link inserted\">google</a>"`. That code doesn't really matter.

Comment: Now it is clear! replaceWith escaping your html code, it's normal! [Read this to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937126/beautifulsoup-replacewith-method-adding-escaped-html-want-it-unescaped)