# Remove Strong tag inside HTML file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to remove Strong tag from my html file in two cases:

1st case :

```
<strong><strong>text1</strong> Some text.</strong>
```

what i want to do is to remove the first strong tag so the output will be like that :

```
<strong>text1</strong> Some text.
```

In second case : if the text's length between `strong` tags is > 100 characters i want the tag to be deleted

Example :

```
<strong>Text that is over 100 characters </strong>
```

to be like this :

```
Text that is over 100 characters
```

Comment: "I am looking for a regex solution that is going to solve the problem for me :)" Uhmnn, thats not how Stackoverflow works. Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, you can [edit] your question to add your own attempt.

Comment: You mention python, can you share the code you are using?

Comment: @0stone0  what i did so far is to open and read the file, about regex pattern i couldn't match it

Comment: @RuiCosta i did add the code but what i want is just the regex pattern that am having issues with, and thanks for your time

Comment: You are asking a *regex* question, so we need to see a *regex* attempt. Otherwise it is very likely your question will get closed. If you are new to regex, consider reading regex tutorials first.

Comment: @WaisKamal i did add regex that matches my 1st case but don't know how to replace it to get the result i want

Comment: @user16085212 you can replace text without using a regex. If all you want is to remove the `<strong>` tag, just do `.replace('<strong>','').replace('</strong>','')`

Comment: @RuiCosta i don't want to remove all strong tags only in my 2 cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently BeautifulSoup supports the `:has()` CSS selector.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap

data = '''
<strong><strong>text1</strong> Some text.</strong>

<strong>Text that is over 100 characters Text that is over 100 characters Text that is over 100 characters Text that is over 100 characters Text that is over 100 characters</strong>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

selector = 'strong:has(strong)'  # works in bs4.__version__ == 4.9.3

for e in soup.select(selector):
    e.unwrap()

for e in soup.select('strong'):
    if e.text and len(e.text) > 100:
        e.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Comment: thank you, it seems regex not really the appropriate for my case, thanks again

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems

Answer (score 0):

regex is not a good choice when it comes to HTML. But maybe this code snippet helps you (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006463/beautiful-soup-4-how-to-replace-a-tag-with-text-and-another-tag))

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
data = """
<html>
<body>
<strong>This is a test</strong>
<strong>This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very  long test</strong>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for strong in soup.findAll('strong'):
    if len(strong.text) > 100:
        # replace the span tag with it's contents
        strong.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Comment: but this code will remove all my strong tags which i don't want to

Comment: sorry, forgot about that (i adapted it)